# Setting flask app with uwsgi and nginx in docker container

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I'm trying to run a Docker container with flask, uwsgi and nginx in a docker container.

my Dockerfile looks so:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER Dockerfiles

# Install required packages and remove the apt packages cache when done.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y \
    ...
    
# install uwsgi 
RUN pip3 install uwsgi

# copy over requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /home/docker/code/

# upgrade pip and install required python packages
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U pip
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r /home/docker/code/requirements.txt

# add (the rest of) our code
COPY ./app /home/docker/code/

# create a systemd unit file
COPY ./app.service /etc/systemd/system/  # Think the problem is here

# start the uwsgi service
RUN systemctl start app  # This is not working
RUN systemctl enable app

# setup all the configfiles
COPY nginx_app /etc/nginx/sites-available/

# enable nginx server block
RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_app /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

# validate syntax
CMD ["nginx", "-t"]

# restart nginx
RUN systemctl restart nginx

# allow nginx
RUN ufw allow 'Nginx Full'
```

and then my app.service so:

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve app
After=network.target

[Service]
User=docker
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/docker/code
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

the nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my_server_ip;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/home/docker/code/myproject.sock;
    }
```

then my uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = app.sock
chmod-socket = 664
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

But when I try to build it, I get this error

> Step 12 : RUN systemctl start app
>
> ---> Running in 79a22c2629db
>
> failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
>
> INFO[0022] The command [/bin/sh -c systemctl start app] returned a non-zero code: 1

I was reading and I think that the problem is with the systemd. I should use supervisord. But I don't have a clue how to do it.

On a "normal" server I could run those commands and it would work, but in a docker container is not working.

The "only" problem I've is that I have to run my app with uwsgi and nginx but I don't get it.

I read many posts and tutorials on Internet and also tried to change [this project](https://github.com/tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-docker/tree/master/python3.6) but it still not working and I'd prefer to use my dockerfile (this one) because it's what I understand.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to run an app as a systemd service inside a Docker container. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I would like to run it with supervisord, but I don't know how to do it. I'm new with docker containers and the only way I knew was with systemd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer.

I resolved it with supervisord.

```
# install uwsgi now because it takes a little while
RUN pip3 install uwsgi

# setup all the configfiles
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx_app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY supervisor_app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/


# copy over our requirements.txt file
COPY requirements.txt /home/docker/code/

# upgrade pip and install required python packages
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -U pip
RUN pip3 --no-cache-dir install -r /home/docker/code/requirements.txt

# add (the rest of) our code
COPY ./app /home/docker/code/

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["supervisord"]
```

and then the supervisor_app.conf looks so

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:uwsgi]
command = /usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /home/docker/code/uwsgi.ini
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0

[program:nginx]
command = /usr/sbin/nginx
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

the uwsg.ini

```
[uwsgi]
callable = app
chdir = /home/docker/code/
wsgi-file = /home/docker/code/wsgi.py
socket = /home/docker/code/app.sock
master = true
processes = 2
chmod-socket = 666
enable-threads = true
```

and my nginx_app.conf

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name my_ip;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///home/docker/code/app.sock;
    }
}
```

and that's it

Comment: Hey, Iam trying to follow these same configuration file with code folder name different at all the places.   Step 8/21 : RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
 ---> Running in 876f489fc21c
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/nginx/nginx.conf: Directory nonexistent

Getting this error while building the image. Can you plz help me out here . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) which has been specifically made to allow the same systemctl commands to be used in a docker container as on a real systemd controlled machine. When running it as CMD then it will start all services that have been enabled.